# Get parameters in PHP after a htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

What would be the htaccess rule of the following case:

I redirect my user to this page:
`system/abc123/step1`

Without a rule it could be:
`system.php?id=abc123&step=step1`

But how can I get via `$_GET` the two parameters passed ?

- abc123
- step1

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for is :

In my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^system/(.+)/(.+)$  system?token=$1&step=$2 [L]
```

In my system.php page:

```
$QUO_Token = $_GET['token']; // abc123
$QUO_Step = $_GET['step'];   // step1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own solution is fine, and it works as expected, without touching php code.

However, for my scripts I adopt a different approach:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .  /processUrl.php [NC, L]
```

By this way, **ALL** (Not Foud) incoming requests all redirected to *processUrl.php*, in which there is a code like this:

```
$uri = (object) parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$uri->thread = explode( '/', substr($uri->path, 1) );

if( 'system' == $uri->thread[0] )
{
    $_GET['id']   = $uri->thread[1];
    $_GET['step'] = $uri->thread[2];
    include( 'system.php' );
}
elseif( 'browse' == $uri->thread[0] )
{
    // Other condition here
}
elseif( isset( $uri->query ) )
{
    // Process ORIGINAL $_GET
}
else
{
    include( 'Your404NotFoundPage.php' );
}
```

I prefer the above method due to:

1. **Transparency:** I can see directly in code how different URI are treated;
2. **Flexibility:** I can add condition or process new url without modify *.htaccess* file.

---

- See more about [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)